# Sorting legend in a donut chart not working ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to define the levels of `mylabel` column in my dataframe based on `Status Count` or `per` column's order (descending). Somehow I cannot get it working and the legend is not sorted the way I wanted. Any ideas why this is not working?

```
    df <- structure(list(Status = structure(1:4, .Label = c("Cancelled", 
    "Closed", "SAP", "Open"), class = "factor"), `Status Count` = c(46L, 
    290L, 814L, 75L)), .Names = c("Status", "Status Count"), row.names = c(NA, 
    4L), class = "data.frame")

    df$per <- round(100* df$`Status Count`/sum(df$`Status Count`),0)
    df$mylabel <- paste(df$Status,'(', df$`Status Count`,') ',df$per,'%')
    df$mylabel <- factor(df$mylabel,levels = reorder(df$mylabel,df$`Status Count`))


    # Barplot
    ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=`Status Count`,fill=mylabel)) +
      geom_bar(width = 0.3, stat = "identity") +
      labs(fill="Status", x=NULL, y=NULL) +
      coord_polar(theta="y", start=0)
```

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce it - legend is ordered

Comment: Use either `df$mylabel <- reorder(df$mylabel,df$`Status Count`)` or `df$mylabel <- factor(df$mylabel,levels = df$mylabel)`

Comment: I just ran it again and I got the same chart I have posted, how is this possible?

Comment: Try new session and load `ggplot2` before creating dataset

Comment: it seems with `reorder` I cannot make it `descending`

Comment: how can I make the legend descending?

Comment: `+ guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))` ?

Comment: @jaySf `+ guides(fill= guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))` did the job, thanks!